# How to shift UIScrollView by one frame's width? (Xcode, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, frame

I'm trying to make an app that uses a functionality similar to that of Snapchat's in which the user can swipe between 3 frames positioned next to each other horizontally. Everything seems to be working but by default, the scrollView presents the view on the furthest left and allows the user to swipe twice to the right to reach the rightmost view. I'd like the scrollview to display the middle view first, allowing the user to swipe left or right but can't seem to get this. Thanks in advance.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds

    let ViewOne = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
    ViewOne.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    let ViewTwo = ExploreViewController(nibName: "ExploreViewController", bundle: nil)
    ViewTwo.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    let ViewThree = ProfileViewController(nibName: "ProfileViewController", bundle: nil)
    ViewThree.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.addChildViewController(ViewOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(ViewOne.view)
    ViewOne.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(ViewTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(ViewTwo.view)
    ViewTwo.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(ViewThree)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(ViewThree.view)
    ViewThree.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    ViewTwo.view.center = CGPoint(x: ViewOne.view.center.x + self.view.frame.width, y: self.view.center.y)
    ViewThree.view.center = CGPoint(x: ViewOne.view.center.x - self.view.frame.width, y: self.view.center.y)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.height)
    print(self.view.center.x)

}
```

Comment: You need to set `contentOffset` to the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)
```

This offsets the scroll view by an amount equal to the width of the view